# Running Firestore transaction at same location is crashing the app

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, transactions

I need to run two transactions at the same time towards one location in the firestore database, but when I implement it gives me error.
I am implementing firestore transactions in flutter application, basically I am calling multilple transactions at press of one button. How should I make sure that this error doesn't occur and doesn't crashes my app.

The code added below clearly shows the calling of the transactions and the transactions are configured accurately and with no issues with them all the issue is happening as they are to be called at same to happen towards the same location.

I have shared the error log as well below. Please guide what should I do.

```
FlatButton(
                  child: Text("btn3"),
                  onPressed: () {
                   Transaction1().postTransaction();
                    Transaction2().postTransaction();
                  },
```

**ERROR LOGS**

> 2020-05-27 18:43:14.529 1022-1344/dev.jideguru.social_app_ui
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
>       Process: dev.jideguru.social_app_ui, PID: 1022
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
>           at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:353)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
>           at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
>        Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: A transaction object cannot be used after its update callback has been
>   invoked.
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.Assert.fail(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:46)
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.Assert.hardAssert(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:31)
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.Transaction.ensureCommitNotCalled(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:246)
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.Transaction.lookup(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:81)
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.Transaction.getAsync(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:191)
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.Transaction.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:228)
>           at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin$5.doInBackground(CloudFirestorePlugin.java:613)
>           at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin$5.doInBackground(CloudFirestorePlugin.java:608)
>           at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)  2020-05-27 18:43:14.529 1022-1346/dev.jideguru.social_app_ui E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #6
>       Process: dev.jideguru.social_app_ui, PID: 1022
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
>           at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:353)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
>           at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
>        Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: A transaction object cannot be used after its update callback has been
>   invoked.
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.Assert.fail(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:46)
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.Assert.hardAssert(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:31)
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.Transaction.ensureCommitNotCalled(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:246)
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.Transaction.lookup(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:81)
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.Transaction.getAsync(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:191)
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.Transaction.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:228)
>           at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin$5.doInBackground(CloudFirestorePlugin.java:613)
>           at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin$5.doInBackground(CloudFirestorePlugin.java:608)
>           at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

Comment: Please show some of your code

Comment: Please if possible add logs of error details being shown on console.

Comment: @Ganapat I have added the error log above, please check

Comment: @Nenroz I have added the calling of the transactions in the above question, transactions are correctly code ,it's just that they are updating the same document at same time.

Comment: @JohnnyWarner this looks like a Flutter firestore lib issue
https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1969

Comment: @JAHDZP for the information, but did you found any solution yet for this issue? I am surprised that Google has not resolve this issue since february.

Comment: Frebase extended for flutter is not a google product

Comment: There appear to be some serious issues with the flutterfire plugin. However, if you are doing two transactions to the same doc at the same time, couldn't you combine the logic into a single transaction? I can't imagine a situation where any business logic would need to be seperated into two seperate transactions for a single document.

Comment: @MaksymMoros I tried as you advised, but it didn't worked , so I used read and write operations to do the needful

Answer (score 1):

Try using an `async` method and `await` keyword before the first transaction to wait before starting the second.